# Swift 1.2 ?? operator

Tags: operators, swift

I just switched to Swift 1.2 and now it does no longer like

```
let v = optionalVal as SomeThing ?? default
```

Apple's release notes do not tell anything about it. Sure I can use `if nil` but the `??` was handy.

Comment: Dear down voters: would you mind to leave a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put it inside a parentheses and forced cast now needs an exclamation mark as! or as?:

```
let v = ( optionalVal as? SomeThing ) ?? default
```

UPDATE:

Apple has just released today Xcode6.3 Beta 2 and seems that it is not needed anymore:

> **Swift Compiler**
>
> This expression now parses correctly, without need for parentheses:
>
> ```
> dict[someKey] as? Int ?? 5
> ```

Comment: Ah thanks. Every day a new syntax. The segmentation fault 11 already got me. Will go back to the old scrap once again. I'm sooo anoyed :-(

Comment: I got this error at all my read-only computed properties and the only way to make it compile was putting them inside a class or an extension

Comment: Honestly I'm sick seeking after workarounds for my Swift code. To say I'm disappointed would be the biggest understatement of the year. SCS still crashes (now every 30 seconds). A company that makes a couple of million dollars per hour must perform better. Since Steve is gone Apple is on the decay. Unfortunately everything else is even worse. I go to bed and cry some tears.

Comment: Still beta they will probably fix it

Comment: Sure. But when? SCS crashes (and XCode) make me crunch teeth all time. That even got worse. We're living in that coding precariat since many months. It feels like Windoze software. Blue screen all day. Even Mickeysoft got almost rid of that. Sigh - will go to bed. It's late here....

Comment: Just stick with the Apple Store version and you will be fine unless you are coding an Apple Watch app

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: I think it should be `as?` and not `as!`, otherwise it would crash if `optionalVal` is nil

Comment: I was just saying that he can't use "as" to force cast anymore using Swift 1.2. It has to be as! or as?